# What's the requirement for the 'Johnny Three-Hats'?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

I've somehow earned the <strike>[Towering Pillar of Hats](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Towering_Pillar_of_Hats)</strike> Johnny Three-Hats, but the description is, well... *less than descriptive*.

[image: Towering Pillar of Hats, a.k.a 'Johnny Three Hats']

Is this hat awarded randomly? If not, how did I earn it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/how-do-i-earn-the-johnny-three-hats-hat

Comment: @MatthewRead Ah thanks, that explains it. Care to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an answer to the same question on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211710/how-do-i-earn-the-johnny-three-hats-hat):

---

The Johnny Three-hats hat is earned by (spoiler below)

> earning three different hats on one site, within one day. Hats earned on different sites, on previous days or before the Winterbash started do not count.

Comment: hmm... so I have 5 hats from this winter bash, yet I don't have a towering stack of hats.  I'm jealous...

Comment: @spartacus - You have to earn the three hats in one day, according to the Meta SO post.

Comment: ohhhhh, damn that stinks